# IBM cloud Public access

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-storage, cloud-object-storage

Can people access my source code when i create public access as object reader in order to host a static website in cloud object storage?

And what are all the risk of **public access**?

Answer (score 0):

When you create an IBM Cloud Object Storage bucket and grant public access to it, then everyone with a link to the bucket and its files, can retrieve them. If the bucket has HTML, JS, CSS files for the website, they would be loaded from the browser of users accessing your website. If you consider the HTML and JavaScript as source code, it would be publicly available.

That is something for every website. You can look at the HTML, JavaScript, and CSS code for Stack Overflow for exactly this page. You probably have no access to the PHP, SQL, etc. code that generated it.